# rails order by field and get 10 items from the middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have build a page that displays a list of ratings in an desc order. 
I want to display only 10 items at a time. how do I select only, say the 11-20 rows 
from the ordered array.
Is it possible to handle this in the query itself, or do i have to fetch the whole table and screen the relevant items?

```
@pics = Rating.order('rating desc').limit(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, use `.offset(10)` in your current query.

In general, search for "rails pagination" on google or here on SO.